# Use JSON to communicate between Python and JavaScript to change CSS of a Website

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a Problem parsing a JSON file in the same path as the javascript. I have tried it with the following code

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'data.json')
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
    var data = request.response;
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
    return jsondata;
    }

console.log(jsondata['text_06']);
```

But I only get the error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: jsondata is not defined at webvisu.js:101

In this case "text_06" is a string from the JSON file which looks like following:

```
{
 "part_count_07": 0,
 "packaging_05": false,
 "emergency_stop_06": false,
 "start_stop_08": false,
 "error_07": false,
 "beg_06": false,
 "beg2_05": false,
 "warning_08": false,
 "text_06": "magazine nearly full",
 "emergency_stop_08": false,
 "warning_07": false,
 "emergency_stop_05": true,
 "information_05": false,
 "text_05": "emergency-stop",
 "mid1_05": false,
 "start_stop_07": false,
 "packing_07": false,
 "part_count_05": 9,
 "start_stop_06": false,
 "end1_05": true,
 "emergency_stop_07": false,
 "error_06": false,
 "packing_08": false,
 "beg1_05": false,
 "beg_07": false,
 "information_08": false,
 "error_05": false,
 "warning_05": false,
 "information_06": false,
 "part_count_06": 10,
 "mid_08": true,
 "warning_06": false,
 "end_07": false,
 "mid_07": false,
 "end2_05": true,
 "beg_08": true,
 "text_07": "",
 "information_07": false,
 "extract_count": 0,
 "error_08": false,
 "end_08": false,
 "part_count_08": 1,
 "text_08": " ",
 "start_stop_05": false,
 "color_07": 0
}
```

My goal is it to change text and colors on the website with the data out of the JSON file which gets overwritten by the following Python script every second which is already fully functional:

```
while True:

    with open('data.json') as f:
        json_data = json.load(f)

    if extract_count == 0:
        ext_note = True

# Storing Station Data ST07
    db_07 = plc_07.db_read(DB_NUM_07, START_ADDRESS, SIZE_07)

    error_07 = (get_bool(db_07, 0, 0))
    warning_07 = (get_bool(db_07, 0, 1))
    information_07 = (get_bool(db_07, 0, 2))
    part_count_07 = (int.from_bytes(db_07[2:4], byteorder='big'))
    start_stop_07 = (get_bool(db_07, 4, 0))
    emergency_stop_07 = (get_bool(db_07, 4, 1))
    beg_07 = (get_bool(db_07, 4, 2))
    mid_07 = (get_bool(db_07, 4, 3))
    end_07 = (get_bool(db_07, 4, 4))
    packing_07 = (get_bool(db_07, 4, 5))
    color_07 = (int.from_bytes(db_07[6:8], byteorder='big'))
    extract_count = (int.from_bytes(db_07[8:10], byteorder='big'))
    text_07 = (get_string(db_07, 10, 266))

    if ext_note:
        set_int(db_07, 8, (json_data['extract_count']))
        set_int(db_07, 6, (json_data['color_07']))
        ext_note = False

    set_bool(db_07, 4, 0, (json_data['start_stop_07']))
    set_bool(db_07, 4, 5, (json_data['packing_07']))
    set_bool(db_07, 4, 6, True)

    plc_07.db_write(DB_NUM_07, START_ADDRESS, db_07)

# Seperating Station Data ST05
    db_05 = plc_05.db_read(DB_NUM_05, START_ADDRESS, SIZE_05)

    error_05 = (get_bool(db_05, 4, 2))
    warning_05 = (get_bool(db_05, 4, 1))
    information_05 = (get_bool(db_05, 4, 0))
    packaging_05 = (get_bool(db_05, 0, 1))
    part_count_05 = (int.from_bytes(db_05[2:4], byteorder='big'))
    start_stop_05 = (get_bool(db_05, 0, 0))
    emergency_stop_05 = (get_bool(db_05, 5, 0))
    beg1_05 = (get_bool(db_05, 4, 3))
    mid1_05 = (get_bool(db_05, 4, 4))
    end1_05 = (get_bool(db_05, 4, 5))
    beg2_05 = (get_bool(db_05, 4, 6))
    end2_05 = (get_bool(db_05, 4, 7))
    text_05 = (get_string(db_05, 6, 262))

    set_bool(db_07, 5, 1, True)

# Packaging Station Data ST08
    db_08 = plc_08.db_read(DB_NUM_08, START_ADDRESS, SIZE_08)

    error_08 = (get_bool(db_08, 0, 0))
    warning_08 = (get_bool(db_08, 0, 1))
    information_08 = (get_bool(db_08, 0, 2))
    part_count_08 = (int.from_bytes(db_08[2:4], byteorder='big'))
    start_stop_08 = (get_bool(db_08, 4, 0))
    emergency_stop_08 = (get_bool(db_08, 4, 1))
    beg_08 = (get_bool(db_08, 4, 2))
    mid_08 = (get_bool(db_08, 4, 3))
    end_08 = (get_bool(db_08, 4, 4))
    packing_08 = (get_bool(db_08, 4, 5))
    text_08 = (get_string(db_08, 6, 262))

    set_bool(db_07, 4, 6, True)

# Handling Station Data ST06
    db_06 = plc_06.db_read(DB_NUM_06, START_ADDRESS, SIZE_06)

    error_06 = (get_bool(db_06, 0, 0))
    warning_06 = (get_bool(db_06, 0, 1))
    information_06 = (get_bool(db_06, 0, 2))
    part_count_06 = (int.from_bytes(db_06[2:4], byteorder='big'))
    start_stop_06 = (get_bool(db_06, 4, 0))
    emergency_stop_06 = (get_bool(db_06, 4, 1))
    beg_06 = (get_bool(db_06, 4, 2))
    text_06 = (get_string(db_06, 6, 262))

    set_bool(db_07, 4, 3, True)

    json_data = {
        "error_07": error_07,
        "warning_07": warning_07,
        "information_07": information_07,
        "part_count_07": part_count_07,
        "start_stop_07": start_stop_07,
        "emergency_stop_07": emergency_stop_07,
        "beg_07": beg_07,
        "mid_07": mid_07,
        "end_07": end_07,
        "text_07": text_07,
        "packing_07": packing_07,
        "color_07": color,
        "extract_count": extract_count,
        "error_05": error_05,
        "warning_05": warning_05,
        "information_05": information_05,
        "packaging_05": packaging_05,
        "part_count_05": part_count_05,
        "start_stop_05": start_stop_05,
        "emergency_stop_05": emergency_stop_05,
        "beg1_05": beg1_05,
        "mid1_05": mid1_05,
        "end1_05": end1_05,
        "beg2_05": beg2_05,
        "end2_05": end2_05,
        "text_05": text_05,
        "error_08": error_08,
        "warning_08": warning_08,
        "information_08": information_08,
        "part_count_08": part_count_08,
        "start_stop_08": start_stop_08,
        "emergency_stop_08": emergency_stop_08,
        "beg_08": beg_08,
        "mid_08": mid_08,
        "end_08": end_08,
        "packing_08": packing_08,
        "text_08": text_08,
        "error_06": error_06,
        "warning_06": warning_06,
        "information_06": information_06,
        "part_count_06": part_count_06,
        "start_stop_06": start_stop_06,
        "emergency_stop_06": emergency_stop_06,
        "beg_06": beg_06,
        "text_06": text_06
    }

    json.dump(json_data, open('data.json', 'w'), indent=1)

    print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=1))
    t.sleep(1)
```

So my Question is how do I correctly parse a JSON file in JavaScript and use it's data within the script. Is it even possible to permanently read the JSON file and update the Website according to the new data?

Comment: I guess line 101 is `console.log(jsondata['text_06']);` , jsondata has not be created at that point in the program flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `jsondata` is defined within the definition of the callback function `request.onload` while you are trying to access it outside the code block. You may want to move `console.log` inside the onload function.

```js
request.onload = function() {
    var data = request.response;
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
    return jsondata;
}

console.log(jsondata['text_06']); // jsondata is not accessible
```

It's also recommended that `request.send()` is called after having `request.onload` defined

```js
request.onload = function() {
    var data = request.response;
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(jsondata['text_06']);
    return jsondata;
    }
request.send();
```

If you want to access `jsondata` outside, you may want to define a global variable outside the onload function and update it once you receive the data.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. How can I update the global variable? I'm new to javascript and I still have a problem to understand it's syntax.

Comment: The scope of the variable depends on where it's defined. To make it accessible globally, you could define it outside the function (e.g., the variable `request` you defined is a global variable already). However, this is flawed because you might need to check whether the data has been assigned to the variable since you don't know when `onload` will be called. It would be a better practice to call another function inside `onload` (like `dataLoaded` in @Kokodoko's answer) and pass the data you want to process. @Joel Pfister

Answer (score 0):

You might call a function when the data is loaded

```
request.onload = function() {
    var data = request.response;
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
    dataLoaded(jsondata);
}

function dataLoaded(jsondata){
    console.log(jsondata['text_06']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine enough but remember that variables declared inside functions are locally scoped, so put your console.log inside the function

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'data.json')
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
    var data = request.response;
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(jsondata['text_06']);
    return jsondata;
    }
```